# KeyError for column that exits in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, error-handling, schedule

This works if I remove the schedule but if i leave it in i receive a key error for 'Symbol'

```
def tweet_and_archive(sl):
    ticker_l = []
    name_l = []
    price_l = []
    price_out_l = []
    date_time = []

    for index, row in sl.iterrows():
        Stock = row['Symbol']
        Price = row['Price']
        Price_out = row['Price Out']
        name_ = row['Name']
        Date_ = row['DateTime']
        if ...

schedule.every().monday.at('12:31').do(lambda: tweet_and_archive(short_list))


while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

This is the short_list dataframe:

```
    Symbol  Name    Price   % Change    Price Out   DateTime
0   ANGPY   Anglo American Platinum Limited 25.82   7.14    NaN 28/02/2022
```

Comment: What does `sl.columns` return?

Comment: Index(['Symbol', 'Name', 'Price', '% Change', 'Price Out', 'DateTime'], dtype='object') is returned